# Which linux version is Azure Function using as the base operating system for its execution environment?

Tags: linux, azure-functions

Coming from AWS Lambda and we are migrating to Azure now...

AWS Lambda uses Amazon Linux 2 as the base operating system for its execution environment.

I need to be careful because I need to provide extra linux / ubuntu library executables to my function, and the versions of the shared libraries I have provided might be built for a different linux version.

As for Azure, which linux version is Azure Function using as the base operating system for its execution environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Azure function created under Linux OS uses Debian Linux version.

In order to check the Linux Version of your Function app.

***Visit Azure Portal> Development Tools > Advanced Tools > SSh > and run the command like below:-***

```bash
cat /etc/os-release
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

> Note- Kudu console in Advanced Tools is only available in Premium Functions tier and App Service plan tier. It is not supported in Consumption Based plan.